# Forcing bash to expand variables in a string loaded from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to work out how to make bash (force?) expand variables in a string (which was loaded from a file).

I have a file called "something.txt" with the contents:

```
hello $FOO world
```

I then run

```
export FOO=42
echo $(cat something.txt)
```

this returns:

```
   hello $FOO world
```

It didn't expand $FOO even though the variable was set. I can't eval or source the file - as it will try and execute it (it isn't executable as it is - I just want the string with the variables interpolated).

Any ideas?

Comment: Be aware of the [security implications of `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: Did you mean the comment to be for the answer below?

Comment: I meant the comment for you. More than one answer proposes the use of `eval` and it's important to be aware of the implications.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson gotcha - I am a bit late replying but good tip. And of course in the intervening years we have had things like "shell shock" so your comment has stood the test of time!  *tips hat*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash expand variable in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049057/bash-expand-variable-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I stumbled on what I think is THE answer to this question: the  `envsubst` command:

```bash
echo "hello \$FOO world" > source.txt
export FOO=42
envsubst < source.txt
```

This outputs: `hello 42 world`

If you would like to continue work on the data in a file `destination.txt`, push this back to a file like this:

```bash
envsubst < source.txt > destination.txt
```

### In case it's not already available in your distro, it's in the
GNU package `gettext`.

@Rockallite

- I wrote a little wrapper script to take care of the '$' problem.

(BTW, there is a "feature" of envsubst, explained at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294400/7088
for expanding only some of the variables in the input, but I
agree that escaping the exceptions is much more convenient.)

Here's my script:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
      ## -*-Shell-Script-*-
CmdName=${0##*/}
Usage="usage: $CmdName runs envsubst, but allows '\$' to  keep variables from
    being expanded.
  With option   -sl   '\$' keeps the back-slash.
  Default is to replace  '\$' with '$'
"

if [[ $1 = -h ]]  ;then echo -e >&2  "$Usage" ; exit 1 ;fi
if [[ $1 = -sl ]] ;then  sl='\'  ; shift ;fi

sed 's/\\\$/\${EnVsUbDolR}/g' |  EnVsUbDolR=$sl\$  envsubst  "$@"
```

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that's _guaranteed_ to not do command substitutions, quote removal, argument processing, etc.

Comment: It just works for fully exported shell vars though (in bash). e.g. S='$a $b'; a=set; export b=exported; echo $S |envsubst;    yields: " exported"

Comment: thanks - I think after all these years, I should accept this answer.

Comment: However, it doesn't handle dollar sign (`$`) escaping, e.g. `echo '\$USER' | envsubst` will output the current username with a prefixing backward slash, not `$USER`.

Comment: seems to get this on a mac with homebrew needs `brew link --force gettext`

Answer (score 30):

you can try

```
echo $(eval echo $(cat something.txt))
```

Comment: Use `echo -e "$(eval "echo -e \"\`<something.txt\`\"")"` if you need new lines kept.

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: But only if your `template.txt` is text. **This operation is dangerous because it executes(evalutes) commands if they are.**

Comment: but this removed double-quote

Comment: Blame it on the subshell.

Answer (score 29):

Many of the answers using `eval` and `echo` kind of work, but break on various things, such as multiple lines, attempting to escaping shell meta-characters, escapes inside the template not intended to be expanded by bash, etc.

I had the same issue, and wrote this shell function, which as far as I can tell, handles everything correctly. This will still strip only trailing newlines from the template, because of bash's command substitution rules, but I've never found that to be an issue as long as everything else remains intact.

```
apply_shell_expansion() {
    declare file="$1"
    declare data=$(< "$file")
    declare delimiter="__apply_shell_expansion_delimiter__"
    declare command="cat <<$delimiter"$'\n'"$data"$'\n'"$delimiter"
    eval "$command"
}
```

For example, you can use it like this with a `parameters.cfg` which is really a shell script that just sets variables, and a `template.txt` which is a template that uses those variables:

```
. parameters.cfg
printf "%s\n" "$(apply_shell_expansion template.txt)" > result.txt
```

In practice, I use this as a sort of lightweight template system.

Comment: This is one of the best tricks I found so far :).  Based on your answer it's so easy to built a function that expand a variable with a string containing references to other variables -- just replace $data with $1 in your function and here we go!  I believe this is the best answer to the original question, BTW.

Comment: Even this has usual `eval` pitfalls. Try adding `; $(eval date)` at the end of any line inside input file and it will run `date` command.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure what you mean; that is actually the desired expansion behavior in this case. In other words, yes, you are supposed to be able to execute arbitrary shell code with this.

Answer (score 8):

You don't want to print each line, you want to *evaluate* it so that Bash can perform variable substitutions.

```
FOO=42
while read; do
    eval echo "$REPLY"
done < something.txt
```

See `help eval` or the Bash manual for more information.

Comment: [`eval` is dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048); you get not only `$varname` expanded (as you would with `envsubst`), but `$(rm -rf ~)` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach (which seems icky, but I am putting it here anyway):

Write the contents of something.txt to a temp file, with an echo statement wrapped around it:

```sh
something=$(cat something.txt)

echo "echo \"" > temp.out
echo "$something" >> temp.out
echo "\"" >> temp.out
```

then source it back in to a variable:

```sh
RESULT=$(source temp.out)
```

and the $RESULT will have it all expanded. But it seems so wrong !

---

Single line solution that doesn't need temporary file :

```sh
RESULT=$(source <(echo "echo \"$(cat something.txt)\""))
#or
RESULT=$(source <(echo "echo \"$(<something.txt)\""))
```

Comment: icky but it is most straight-forward, simple, and works.

Comment: This is as dangerous as the other answers containing `eval` as it implies an implicit `eval`. Try `echo '$(rm -rf /)' > something.txt` and then your solution ...

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the variable references to be expanded (an objective that I had for myself) you could do the below.

```
contents="$(cat something.txt)"
echo $(eval echo \"$contents\")
```

(The escaped quotes around $contents is key here)

Comment: I have tried this one, however the $() removes line endings in my case which breaks the resulting string

Comment: I changed the eval line to `eval "echo \"$$contents\""` and it preserved the whitespace

Comment: @khusseini I think you mean `eval "echo \"$contents\""` with a single dollar sign? `$$contents` is the process ID of the script followed by the word `contents`.

Comment: This is as dangerous as the other answers containing `eval` . Try `echo '$(rm -rf /)' > something.txt` and then your solution ...

Answer (score 3):

1. If *something.txt* has only *one* line, a `bash` method, (a shorter version of [*Michael Neale's* "icky" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10695043/6136214)),
   using *process* & *command substitution*:

   ```
   FOO=42 . <(echo -e echo $(<something.txt))
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   hello 42 world
   ```

   Note that `export` isn't needed.
2. If *something.txt* has one or more lines, a *GNU* `sed` **`e`***valuate* method:

   ```
   FOO=42 sed 's/"/\\\"/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' something.txt
   ```

Comment: I found the `sed` evaluate to best fit my purpose. I needed to produce scripts from templates, which would have values filled from variables exported in another config file. It handles properly escaping for command expansion e.g. put `\$(date)` in the template to get `$(date)` in the output. Thanks!

Comment: This is as dangerous as the other answers containing `eval` as it implies an implicit `eval`. Try `echo '$(rm -rf /)' > something.txt` and then your solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Following  solution:

- allows replacing  of  variables  which are  defined
- leaves  unchanged  variables placeholders which  are  not defined.  This is  especially  useful  during automated  deployments.
- supports  replacement of  variables  in  following formats:

  `${var_NAME}`

  `$var_NAME`
- reports  which variables are  not defined  in environment and  returns  error  code for such  cases

```
    TARGET_FILE=someFile.txt;
    ERR_CNT=0;

    for VARNAME in $(grep -P -o -e '\$[\{]?(\w+)*[\}]?' ${TARGET_FILE} | sort -u); do     
      VAR_VALUE=${!VARNAME};
      VARNAME2=$(echo $VARNAME| sed -e 's|^\${||g' -e 's|}$||g' -e 's|^\$||g' );
      VAR_VALUE2=${!VARNAME2};

      if [ "xxx" = "xxx$VAR_VALUE2" ]; then
         echo "$VARNAME is undefined ";
         ERR_CNT=$((ERR_CNT+1));
      else
         echo "replacing $VARNAME with $VAR_VALUE2" ;
         sed -i "s|$VARNAME|$VAR_VALUE2|g" ${TARGET_FILE}; 
      fi      
    done

    if [ ${ERR_CNT} -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "Found $ERR_CNT undefined environment variables";
        exit 1 
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo=45
file=something.txt       # in a file is written: Hello $foo world!
eval echo $(cat $file)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: This is as dangerous as the other answers containing `eval` . Try `echo '$(rm -rf /)' > something.txt` and then your solution ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ eval echo $(cat something.txt)
hello 42 world
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: This is as dangerous as the other answers containing `eval`. Try `echo '$(rm -rf /)' > something.txt` and then your solution ...

Answer (score 0):

```
catexp () {
    local function_name="${FUNCNAME[0]}"
    local uuid="$(uuidgen)"
    if [[ $# = 0 && -t 0 ]]; then
        echo "$function_name: Missing argument and stdin." >&2
        return 1
    fi
    . <(
        printf -- '%s\n' "cat << ${uuid}"
        cat "$@" 2> >(perl -spe 's/^cat: /$function_name: /' -- -function_name="$function_name" >&2)
        exit_code=$?
        printf -- '\n%s\n' "${uuid}"
        printf -- '%s\n' "(exit ${exit_code})"
    ) | perl -0pe 's/\n$//'
    pipestatus
    return $?
}

pipestatus () {
    set "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
    local i
    for (( i=1; i<$#; i++ )); do
        if [[ ${!i} -ge 1 ]]; then break; fi
    done
    return ${!i}
}

echo "hello \$FOO world" > source.txt
FOO=42 # Also without export
catexp source.txt
```

Or:

```
catexp < source.txt
```

Or:

```
cat source.txt | catexp
```

Also:

```
catexp file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
expenv () {
    LF=$'\n'
    echo "cat <<END_OF_TEXT${LF}$(< "$1")${LF}END_OF_TEXT" | bash
    return $?
}

expenv "file name"
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. I recommend reading, [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score -2):

`envsubst` is a great solution (see LenW's answer) if the content you're substituting is of "reasonable" length.

In my case, I needed to substitute in a file's content to replace the variable name. `envsubst` requires that the content be exported as environment variables and bash has a problem when exporting environment variables that are more than a megabyte or so.

### awk solution

Using cuonglm's [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141398/149244) from a different question:

```
needle="doc1_base64" # The "variable name" in the file. (A $ is not needed.)
needle_file="doc1_base64.txt" # Will be substituted for the needle 
haystack=$requestfile1 # File containing the needle
out=$requestfile2
awk "BEGIN{getline l < \"${needle_file}\"}/${needle}/{gsub(\"${needle}\",l)}1" $haystack > $out
```

This solution works for even large files.

Comment: The question was "Forcing bash to expand variables in a string loaded from a file" and this is not an answer to it. Maybe the variable names are not even known upfront, maybe they can be whatever the user wants them to be. This is replacing text with text but that wasn't asked.

Answer (score -3):

The following works: `bash -c "echo \"$(cat something.txt)"\"`

Comment: This is not just inefficient, but also extremely dangerous; it doesn't just run safe expansions like `$foo`, but unsafe ones like `$(rm -rf ~)`.