# How to replace text inside another string which matches a regex pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
${[a-zA-Z0-9._:]*}
```

I have used the above pattern for grepping words similar to ${SomeText}. How can I replace 'SomeText' with some other string i.e ${SomeText} --> SomeString in my bash script?

Example:
file.txt

```
text text text ${SomeText1} text text ${SomeText2} text text text text text text
text text text text ${SomeText3} text text text text text text ${SomeText4} text
...
```

my script file:

```
SomeText1="foo"
SomeText2="bar"
..
```

I want to replace ${SomeText1} to $SomeText1 which will be replaced by foo.
Similarly
${SomeText2} > $SomeText2 > bar

```
text text text foo text text bar text text text text text text
text text text text baz text text text text text text qux text
...
```

Comment: Please share some example for what do you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing bash to expand variables in a string loaded from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683349/forcing-bash-to-expand-variables-in-a-string-loaded-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`

```
echo '${SomeText}, SomeText' | sed "s/\${SomeText}/\${SomeOtherText}/g"
```

will output

```
${SomeOtherText}, SomeText
```

if you need to use variables in sed, do it like this

```
a="SomeText"
b="SomeOtherText"

echo '${SomeText}, SomeText' | sed "s/\${$a}/\${$b}/g"
```

The output will be the same as above

EDIT:
Better use arrays to store that strings

```
 SomeText[1]="foo"
 SomeText[2]="bar"

 i=0

 while [[ $i < $MAX_i ]]
 do
   ((i++))
   sed -i "s/\${SomeText[$i]}/${SomeText[$i]}/g"
 done
```

If you really need your approach, you will need double evaluation

```
 SomeText[1]="foo"
 SomeText[2]="bar"

 i=0

 while [[ $i < $MAX_i ]]
 do
   ((i++))
   toRepl="SomeText"$i
   scriptToCall=$(eval echo "s/\\\${$toRepl}/$`eval echo ${toRepl}`/g")
   sed -i $scriptToCall file
 done
```

So you iterate thru all indices (SomeText1, SomeText2, ...), save the current into var `toRepl`, evaluate the script you want to call, for i=1 it will be `scriptToCall="s/\${SomeText[1]}/foo/g"` cause you double evaluate `toRepl -> ${SomeText1} -> foo` and you pass that script to sed :)

Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script:

```
while IFS='=' read k v; do
   v=$(tr -d '"' <<< $v)
   sed -i.bak "s/\${$k}/$v/g" file.txt
done < script
```