# How to use variables in {a..z} range construct?

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I am trying to do a loop similar to this basic one:

```
storage-33:~#  echo {a..z}           
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

However I have two variables I set on my script called $first_sd and $last_sd

I have been unsuccessful when running it on my shell. The behaviour is not the loop from A to Z I expected. Its actually not doing the loop at all, do I need to convert my variable or is there a trick to make this work? See my bad example here of what I am trying to do (this does not work)

```
storage-33:~# for i in {$first_sd..$last_sd}; do echo HI $i; done
HI {a..h}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related (issue is 2nd level evaluation in both cases): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683349/forcing-bash-to-expand-variables-in-a-string-loaded-from-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval`

```
for i in $(eval echo "{$first_sd..$last_sd}"); do echo HI $i; done
```

Comment: thanks! very helpful. Wasn't aware of the eval option

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` remembering to escape the appropriate characters:

```
eval "for i in {$first_sd..$last_sd}; do echo HI \$i; done"
```

Comment: thanks! very helpful. Wasn't aware of the eval option