# Load environment variables from a shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a file with some environment variables that I want to use in a python script

The following works form the command line

```
$ source myFile.sh
$ python ./myScript.py
```

and from inside the python script I can access the variables like

```
import os
os.getenv('myvariable')
```

How can I source the shell script, then access the variables, from with the python script?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean how do you *set* environment variables?

Comment: i want to call 'source myFile.sh' from inside the python script and then access the variables

Comment: So you just want to know how to run a command from Python? Have you tried searching for *that*? *"load environment variables"* seems **completely incidental** to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know how to run a bash command from python, but is there a built in way of sourcing the file ?

Comment: related: [Calling the “source” command from subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7040592/4279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulating Bash 'source' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503719/emulating-bash-source-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are saying backward environment propagation, sorry, you can't. It's a security issue. However, directly source environment from python is definitely valid. But it's more or less a manual process.

```
import subprocess as sp

SOURCE = 'your_file_path'
proc = sp.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'source {} && env'.format(SOURCE)], stdout=sp.PIPE)

source_env = {tup[0].strip(): tup[1].strip() for tup in map(lambda s: s.strip().split('=', 1), proc.stdout)}
```

Then you have everything you need in `source_env`.

If you need to write it back to your local environment (which is not recommended, since `source_env` keeps you clean):

```
import os

for k, v in source_env.items():
    os.environ[k] = v
```

---

Another tiny attention needs to be paid here, is since I called `bash` here, you should expect the rules are applied here too. So if you want your variable to be seen, you will need to export them.

```
export VAR1='see me'
VAR2='but not me'
```

Comment: That's not going to work properly for all possible environment variable values -- the output of `env` isn't intended to be unambiguously parsed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true. there are corner cases. one possible way to actually deal with it will need another script that prints `k=v` delimited by `\0`.

Comment: Indeed. One could even `cat /proc/self/environ`, which will emit exactly that format, if the only OS that needs to be supported is Linux. :)

Answer (score -3):

You can **not** load environmental variables in general from a bash or shell script, it is a different language. You will have to use bash to evaluate the file and then somehow print out the variables and then read them. see [Forcing bash to expand variables in a string loaded from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683349/forcing-bash-to-expand-variables-in-a-string-loaded-from-a-file)