# String expansion - escaped quoted variable to value

Tags: bash, sed, cat, variable-expansion

To get started, here's the script I'm running to get the offending string:

```
# sed finds all sourced file paths from inputted file.
#
# while reads each match output from sed to $SOURCEFILE variable.
# Each should be a file path, or a variable that represents a file path.
# Any variables found should be expanded to the full path.
#
# echo and calls are used for demonstractive purposes only 
# I intend to do something else with the path once it's expanded.

PATH_SOME_SCRIPT="/path/to/bash/script"

while read -r SOURCEFILE; do
    echo "$SOURCEFILE"
    "$SOURCEFILE"
    $SOURCEFILE
done < <(cat $PATH_SOME_SCRIPT | sed -n -e "s/^\(source\|\.\|\$include\) //p")
```

You may also wish to use the following to test this out as mock data:

```
[ /path/to/bash/script ]

#!/bin/bash
source "$HOME/bash_file"
source "$GLOBAL_VAR_SCRIPT_PATH"

echo "No cow powers here"
```

For the **tl;dr** crew, basically the `while` loop spits out the following on the mock data:

```
"$HOME/bash_file"
bash: "$HOME/bash_file": no such file or directory
bash: "$HOME/bash_file": no such file or directory
"$GLOBAL_VAR_SCRIPT_PATH"
"$GLOBAL_VAR_SCRIPT_PATH": command not found
"$GLOBAL_VAR_SCRIPT_PATH": command not found
```

My question is, can you get the variable to expand correctly, e.g., print "/home//bash_file" and "/expanded/variable/path"? I should also state that **although `eval` works I do not intend to use it because of its [potential insecurities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).**

Protip that any variable value used in `cat | sed` would be available globally, including to the calling script, so it's not because the script cannot call the variable value.

---

**FIRST SOLUTION ATTEMPT**

Using anubhava's `envsubst` solution:

```
SOMEVARIABLE="/home/nick/.some_path"
while read -r SOURCEFILE; do 
    echo "$SOURCEFILE"
    envsubst <<< "$SOURCEFILE"; 
done < <(echo -e "\"\$SOMEVARIABLE\"\n\"$HOME/.another_file\"")
```

This outputs the following:

```
"$SOMEVARIABLE"
""
"/home/nick/.another_file"
"/home/nick/.another_file"
```

Unfortunately, it does not expand the variable! Oh dear :(

---

**SECOND SOLUTION ATTEMPT**

Based upon the first attempt:

```
export SOMEVARIABLE="/home/nick/.some_path"
while read -r SOURCEFILE; do 
    echo "$SOURCEFILE"
    envsubst <<< "$SOURCEFILE"; 
done < <(echo -e "\"\$SOMEVARIABLE\"\n\"$HOME/.another_file\"")
unset SOMEVARIABLE
```

which produces the results we wanted without `eval` and without messing with global variables (for too long anyway), hoorah!

---

Good runner-ups were further suggested using `eval` (although potentially unsafe) which can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126808/2483271) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20316582/548225) (link courtesy of anubhava's extended comments).

Comment: Please note if you read this question before this comment that I've changed two of the output errors in the third comment block as they were incorrect - apologies!

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with all the relevant details and suggested links +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, can you get the variable to expand correctly, e.g., print `"/home//bash_file"` and `"/expanded/variable/path"`?

Yes you can use [`envsubst` program](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html), that substitutes the values of environment variables:

```
while read -r sourceFile; do
   envsubst <<< "$sourceFile"
done < <(sed -n "s/^\(source\|\.\|\$include\) //p" "$PATH_SOME_SCRIPT")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm afraid I have to take that back - this doesn't work 100%. Please check the updated question

Comment: It will work, just add `export` before your variable declaration to make it available to environment. So make it `export SOMEVARIABLE="/home/nick/.some_path"`

Comment: You are a god! Thank you, is there a way to do it without exporting them? Sometimes I just want the variables to be localised to a function. Apparently `export local variable=` is valid bash, but it is still available outside the scope of the function.

Comment: In theory it might be possible but that solution will be without the simplicity of using `envsubst`. I will research if it is possible then I will update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the library we are including this is is quite large and variable scope has been of issue before because of non-localised variables. Again, it's outside the scope (heh) of the question, but your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20316582/548225) though I believe even that will be unsafe.

Comment: Fantastic research - I've ran across similar solutions. I think for safety, `export VARIABLE` and then using `unset VARIABLE` once the operations are complete is the best method to meet all goals - the question will shortly be updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to recursively expand variables in bash.  Try

```
expanded=$(eval echo $SOURCEFILE)
```

inside your loop.  `eval` runs the expanded command you give it.  Since `$SOURCEFILE` isn't in quotes, it will be expanded to, e.g., `$HOME/whatever`.  Then the `eval` will expand the `$HOME` before passing it to `echo`.  `echo` will print the result, and `expanded=$(...)` will put the printed result in `$expanded`.

Comment: I'm only avoiding the downvote because I didn't specify no `eval`! I actually knew this method worked, but `eval` is extremely insecure and should be avoided at all costs as a solution in these kinds of scripts unless used very carefully - unfortunately it has not been used carefully enough in this answer to be considered safe IMO. Please read further here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: Please note I've updated the answer to reflect the above comment - apologies for not doing that sooner. Upvoted as a correct-before-edit solution.