# Execute bash within some text file

Tags: bash

I would like to create a templating system that executes bash within a text file.

For example, let's consider we created a simple `template.yaml` file:

```yaml
my_path: $(echo ${PATH})
my_ip: $(curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/)
some_const: "foo bar"
some_val: $(echo -n $MY_VAR | base64)
```

The desire is to execute each one, such that the result may look like:

```yaml
my_path: /Users/roman/foo
my_ip: 1.2.3.4
some_const: "foo bar"
some_val: ABC
```

How would I go about doing such a substitution?

---

Reasons for wanting this:

- There are many values, and doing something like a sed or [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) isn't practical
- It would be common to apply a series of piped transformations
- The configuration file would be populated from numerous sources, all of them essentially bash commands
- I do need to create a yaml file of a specific format (ultimately used by another tool)
- I could create aliases etc to increase readability
- By having it execute in it's own shell none of the semi-sensitive values are stored as in history or as files.

I'm not married to this approach, and would happily attempt a recommendation that fulfils the reasons.

Comment: Don't shy away from the `"Icky"` approach either in the linked question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @joshmeranda for pointing me in the right direction, [this solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684144/3421652)

```
echo -e "$(eval "echo -e \"`<template.yaml`\"")"
```

While eval can be dangerous, in my case its usage is controlled.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, you can try though:
you can create a script: `script.sh` which will take one argument as `.yaml` file and will expand the variables inside that file:

`script.sh` :

```
    echo 'cat <<EOF' >  temp.sh
    cat "$1"         >> temp.sh
    echo 'EOF'       >> temp.sh
    bash temp.sh
    rm temp.sh
```

and you can invoke the script as from the command line : `./script.sh template.yaml`